# MySQL query match against dont want find my text

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

This is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  title text NOT NULL,
  body text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT (title,body)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `title`, `body`) VALUES 
('1', 'Lorem Ipsum', 'IT,cool'), 
('2', 'Lorem Ipsum (cont)', 'Some other text.');
```

When I call this query it will return result:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('cool' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but this not:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('IT' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Here is demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/368c12/1 .

Why? What is wrong and how to solve?

Comment: The default minimum word length is 4, `it` is too short. Also, such a common word will be in the stopwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The minimum length of the word for full-text searches as of follows :
> Three characters for InnoDB search indexes.
> Four characters for MyISAM search indexes.
> Stop words are words that are very common such as 'on', 'the' or 'it', appear in almost every document. These type of words are ignored during searching.

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

You should try to find your string using the LIKE operator :

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE CONCAT(title, body) LIKE '%IT%';
```